# Insert <li> in <ul> carousel dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to insert dynamically whit this function but I don't know why it's no working.

It's my jQuery function...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').removeClass('no-js');
        //$('#my-carousel-1').carousel();
        $('#my-carousel-2').carousel({
            itemsPerPage: 6,
            itemsPerTransition: 6,
            speed: 500
        });
        $('#my-carousel-3').carousel({
            itemsPerPage: 6,
            itemsPerTransition: 6,
            easing: 'linear',
            noOfRows: 2
        });



        $('#MainContent_btnAddTag').click(function () {
            var inp = $("#MainContent_txtSearch").val();
            if ($.trim(inp).length > 0) {

                var num = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);

                var lit = '<li value="0" class="color-' + num + '">testInsert</li>';

                $('#my-carousel-2 ul').append(lit);
            }
        });
    });
```

my HTML, there are a differents things that I can't change like cssClass or something like this.

```
<div class="frmfield">
<WWTB:WWTextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" CssClass="tBox" LabelValue="Search"
 Text="Search" ErrorMessage="Please enter a" 
 ValidationType="NotBlank" ErrorClass="error"></WWTB:WWTextBox>
 <div class="frmbtnblock">
 here my button to add tags
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddTag" Text="Add tag" CssClass="btn btnRight" runat="server" />
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="frmfield">
 <div id="my-carousel-2" class="carousel">
 <ul id="ulSelected">
 <%-- here my new li --%>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where is `#button`? And where did you place the code? Within `document.ready`?

Comment: Why are u using: $('#my-carousel ul').append(lit); use the ul directly: $('#ulSelected').append(lit);

Comment: Working fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/7LxD8/

Comment: thanks for your help, yeah; my button is in document.ready.

Comment: I was trying to use only $('ulSelected').append(lit); but I can't see anything.

Comment: @Nick is right. So what is the problem? I think Jotch does not have a button with id "button".

Comment: @Jotch it should be `$('#ulSelected')` not `$('ulSelected')`

Comment: lol, thanks for this. I know but it is not the problem. ;)

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I have this button. I've only forgotten put there.

Comment: Ok, I think that is my library. I am used <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> Maybe there is the problem. But I can't to change this because other elements won't work neither. Some idea?

Comment: no not problem with that. I checked Nick fiddle and it is working.

Comment: Then, I don't know what happens. :(

Comment: that is why we are asking to show the actual html and javascript.

Comment: @Jotch How are you running the file, if you just open it in your browser ie `file://`, then it won't work if you use `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com`, as the double `/` only works when you run it through a web server. You could try changing the `//` to `http://` instead and see if that works.

Comment: @NickR thanks for your help. I've changed this and remains as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to construct a new `li` element, programatically set its attributes and append it to the `ul`.

```
var $ul = $('#ulSelected');

$('<li>')
  .attr('value', 0)
  .addClass('color-' + num)
  .text('testInsert')
  .appendTo($ul);
```

I find that this style leads to more readable code than including chunks of HTML in your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#ulSelected').append('<li value="0" class="color-' + num + '">testInsert</li>');
```